# How to set the default @Transactional timeout globally

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I've a number of controllers with a lot of methods that deal with transactions... and I want to set transaction timeout to 60 for **all** of them:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Transactional(timeout = 60)
    public void myMethod1(...) {
    }

    @Transactional(timeout = 60)
    public void myMethod2(...) {
    }

    ...
}
```

How do I set the default timeout to 60 globally so that I no longer need to specify `timeout = 60` for each method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default timeout by configuring the bean of the transaction management :

```
@Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
        = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setDefaultTimeout(10);
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
        entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );
      return transactionManager;
   }
```

here an url that shows how to configure transaction manager for the annotation Transactional : https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Comment: I would suggest using a `BeanPostProcessor` to set the property, so that one can rely on the auto-configuration of Spring Boot to construct the proper tx-manager.

Answer (score 8):

You can use property:
**spring.transaction.default-timeout=** # Default transaction timeout in seconds.

Comment: Spring documentation supporting this answer:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.7/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.transaction.spring.transaction.default-timeout