# Set Timeout of JPA Methods in Spring Boot 2.3.5 version with Hibernate - Oracle DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot 2.3.5 version with Oracle 12c DB and performing the DB operation using spring boot data jpa/hibernate.

Sometimes the DB operation is taking more time and I need to set the timeout for JPA Repository methods - saveandflush, deletebyid, save etc.

Need the guidance to define the timeout for the JPA JPA Repository methods - saveandflush, deletebyid, save in Spring Boot 2.3.5 Application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the default @Transactional timeout globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70664498/how-to-set-the-default-transactional-timeout-globally)

Answer (score 0):

There're two ways to set a timeout:

1. In configuration properties

   spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=1000
2. Programatically in the code

   ```
   @Bean
   HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
       dataSource.setDataSourceProperties(properties());
       ...
       return dataSource;
   }

   Properties oracleProperties() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT", 1000);
       ...
       return properties;
   }
   ```

I take as an assumption you're using hikari datasource

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).